# Is the 'limit' tag a good thing?

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose the 'limit' tag for, ahem, elimination. It's one of those common words that adds nothing as a tag.

Comment: This is for Stack Overflow, I presume?  Because on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) it's probably a useful tag.

Comment: And integration, derivative, diferential-equation ... ?

Comment: yup. correct. so.

Comment: the value on so is, however, epsilon.

Comment: Numerical Methods are a core competence for programmers. Languages are just voluble tools.

Answer (score 3):

[limit](/questions/tagged/limit) looks like a legitimate tag to me. In Unix programming, “limit” is the proper technical term for a limitation set on the amount of resources a program can use (e.g. no more than *x* kB of memory or *y* seconds of CPU time). SQL is outside my area expertise, but the use of “limit” as a tag to discuss `LIMIT` clauses looks appropriate as well. So maybe some individual uses are ill-advised, but not the tag itself.